# Can I put any ranged weapon on a Crisis Battlesuit?

Tags: warhammer-40k, tau

I've read the Codex (6th) entry for the XV8 Crisis Team and it says:

> Any Crisis Shas'ui may take up to three items from the Ranged Weapons
>   and/ or Support Systems lists.

I can see only one list of **Ranged Weapons** in the codex (the one which lists all ranged weapons) so it seems that I can put any weapon on them. Is my interpretation of the rule wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The Army List entry would be referring to the *"Tau Empire Wargear List"* on pg 95.

This lists 5 sections: Ranged Weapons, Signature Systems, Drones, Support Systems and Vehicle battle Systems.

So they could take up to 3 items from the Ranged Weapons and/or Support Systems lists on this page.

Comment: Is that a **"No"** to my question: "Is my interpretation of the rule wrong?"?

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly you mean.

You could be referring to one of two "Ranged Weapons" tables. The one on page 95 in the wargear list (before the list of unit entries), or the one in the "Reference" section at the back of the book.

If you mean the wargear list on page 95, then you are correct, you may take up to 3 items from that list at the stated cost.

If you mean the reference list, which lists every single ranged weapon available to the tau army, then you are incorrect.